# Возможно ли отнять число в PlayerPrefs.SetInt?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможно ли отнять число в PlayerPrefs.SetInt?

```
Int a = 1;
a -= 1;
```

Тогда a будет равно 0;
Таким же образом хотел бы отнять число в `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", ...)`
Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: вы имеете в виду что хотите отнять что то от переменной и поместить её в SetInt() ? или что то типа PlayerPrefs.SetInt("value", value-1); ?

Comment: @Нет,я хотел узнать могу ли я отнять число от уже установленного "value".

Comment: вы можете взять значение. Изменить его. И снова сохранить

Comment: @Andrey Это означает что я не могу отнять число от уже установленного "value"?

Comment: Напрямую не сможете. Надо загружать, менять и перезаписывать. Можете написать свой метод для этого действия, конечно.

Comment: @Veudd, на самом деле вы нигде напрямую не отнимаете. `-=` просто синтаксический сахар, а по сути это всегда уравнение вида `a = a - 1`

Comment: @M.Green только не уравнение, а выражение